# Drag, Drop, and Resize Images with canvas

Tags: image, canvas, drag-and-drop, transform, kineticjs

This is a very nice demo of canvas and kineticjs. Anyway if an image is drawn to a size of zero pixel all images on the canvas disappear. I'm looking for alternatives to kineticjs in pure JS, or is kineticjs the best solution for this job?

[link] http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-resize-and-invert-images/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this fairly easy with straight JS. Check out Simon Sarrisss's [tutorial here](http://simonsarris.com/blog/225-canvas-selecting-resizing-shape).